# How do i use localhost as my domain for recaptcha

Tags: flutter, recaptcha, flutter-web

I am digging my hands on flutter web, and i want to integrate recaptcha for my basic form. I have configured recaptcha on the google console. However for my development purpose when i am using it with the localhost domain i always get this error

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html' as html;


class platformViewRegistry {
static registerViewFactory(String viewId, dynamic cb) {
// ignore:undefined_prefixed_name
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(viewId, cb);
}
}

class TestPlugin extends StatefulWidget {
TestPlugin();

_TestPluginState createState() => _TestPluginState();
}

class _TestPluginState extends State<TestPlugin> {
String createdViewId = 'map_element';
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
@override
void initState() {
// ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    createdViewId,
    (int viewId) => html.IFrameElement()
      ..width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()
      ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString()
      ..srcdoc = """<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>reCAPTCHA</title>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style='height: 50px;width: 100px;'></div>
<form action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" 
    data-sitekey="my_key"
    data-callback="captchaCallback"></div>

</form>
<script>
  function captchaCallback(response){
    //console.log('the response is: '+response);
    alert(response);
    if(typeof Captcha!=="undefined"){
      Captcha.postMessage(response);
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>"""
      ..style.border = 'none');

super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(children: [
      TextFormField(),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Container(
        height: 140,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: HtmlElementView(
          viewType: createdViewId,
        ),
      ),
      ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Submit'))
    ]),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I have entered the proper data-site key which i haven't mentioned in the code above. I have also disabled  Verify the origin of reCaptcha solutions on the console. I have also added localhost to the list of my domains.[image] Any help will be appreciated.

Edits: This probably doesn't have any issues with the site and the secret keys as i was able to achieve this using NodeJS with the same set of keys. This has to do something with flutter and v2 reCaptcha i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Google use to have keys for testing localhost but it looks like you just need to add localhost as a domain now.

See google docs:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#localhost_support

Comment: I just edited my question. I have added localhost to the list of my domains already, still no luck !

Comment: just wondering do you get any errors in the console log? The issue is most likely not with the google recapcha.

Comment: There's no error on both my browser console as well as the vscode debug console.

Comment: I wonder if flutter is causing an issue forcing it to use v2 instead of v3. Try the v2 test keys located here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Comment: tried everything out, but nothing works dont know why.. Tried with the test keys, tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, I actually want to use reCAPTCHA checkbox which is v2. Haven't found any plugin which supports the web platform.

Comment: The problem was with the srcdoc attribute of the iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, but it seems that it doesn't work with `localhost`. But if you add `127.0.0.1` it will work if you change your url for this ip address instead of 'localhost'.

Comment: I found placing both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in the list of accepted domains it will work with the URL containing `localhost`.  I believe it has something to do with the _hosts_ file for how `localhost` is defined

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works after putting the html code in a file. Then update the `IFrameElement's src`.

```
iframeElement.src = '/assets/test_captcha.html';
```